# Problema com inserção de múltiplas notificações

Tags: php, mysql

Boa noite.

Eu tenho um sistema de notificações em que os utilizadores recebem notificações dos utilizadores de quem eles estão a seguir. Por exemplo, "*João comentou x posts*" e está a funcionar quando, por exemplo, existe só um seguidor. O problema está quando a pessoa tem mais que um seguidor em que a mesma notificação tem que ser enviada para todos os utilizadores que ele está seguindo.

**Tabela `notificacoes`:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `notificacoes` (
`notificacao_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_destino_notificacao` int(11) NOT NULL,
`notificacao` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`tipo` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`data` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`notificacao_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;
```

**Tabela `notificacoes_visualizacao`:**

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `notificacoes_visualizacao` (
`id_notificacao` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_usuario_que_visualizou` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_notificacao`,`id_usuario_que_visualizou`),
KEY `fk_notificacao_visualizacao_usuario` (`id_usuario_que_visualizou`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Código PHP:**

```sql
   <?php

    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
    //Alteramos o cabeçalho para que o retorno seja do tipo JSON 
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

    session_start();

    require_once("../funcoes/funcoes.php");

    $user_actual = $_REQUEST['user_logado'];


    $result_notificacoes = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM notificacoes as noti 
                                        LEFT JOIN notificacoes_visualizacao as noti_vi ON noti_vi.id_notificacao = noti.notificacao_id
                                        INNER JOIN users_social as user ON user.id = noti.user_id
                                        WHERE noti.user_id IN (SELECT seg.followed FROM seguidores as seg WHERE seg.follower = :user_actual) 
                                        AND noti_vi.id_usuario_que_visualizou is NULL 
                                        OR noti.user_destino_notificacao = :user_atual2");                                  

    $result_notificacoes->bindParam(':user_actual', $user_actual, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result_notificacoes->bindParam(':user_atual2', $user_actual, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result_notificacoes->execute();


    $return = array();

    $notificacoes = $result_notificacoes->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($notificacoes as $row_notificacoes) {

    // MOSTRA TEMPO DO POST

    $data_actual = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $data = strtotime($row_notificacoes['data']);

    $data_post = strtotime($data_actual) - $data;

    switch (post_data) {
        // Segundos
        case ($data_post < 60):
            $count = $data_post;
            if($count == 0)
                $count = "Agora mesmo";
            elseif ($count == 1)
                $suffix = "segundo atrás";
            else
                $suffix = "segundos atrás";
        break;
        // Minutos
        case ($data_post > 60 && $data_post < 3600):
            $count = floor($data_post/60);
            if($count == 1)
                $suffix = "minuto atrás";
            else
                $suffix = "minutos atrás";
        break;
        // Horas
        case ($data_post > 3600 && $data_post < 86400):
            $count = floor($data_post/3600);
            if($count == 1)
                $suffix = "hora atrás";
            else
                $suffix = "horas atrás";
        break;
        // Dias
        case ($data_post > 86400 && $data_post < 2629743):
            $count = floor($data_post/86400);
            if($count == 1)
                $suffix = "dia atrás";
            else
                $suffix = "dias atrás";
        break;
        // Meses
        case ($data_post > 2629743 && $data_post < 31556926):
            $count = floor($data_post/2629743);
            if($count == 1)
                $suffix = "mês atrás";
            else
                $suffix = "meses atrás";
        break;
    }       

    $sql = $conexao->prepare("INSERT INTO notificacoes_visualizacao (id_notificacao, id_usuario_que_visualizou) VALUES (:id_notificacao, :id_usuario_que_visualizou)");
    $sql->bindParam(':id_notificacao', $row_notificacoes['notificacao_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->bindParam(':id_usuario_que_visualizou', $user_actual, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    $sql->execute();

    $return[] = '
        <table border="0" class="barra_notificacoes" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" width="10%">
                    <div style="margin-left: 4px; margin-top: 5px;"><img width="50" height="50" src="'.$row_notificacoes['user_foto'].'"></div>
                </td>
                <td valign="top" width="50%">
                    <div style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 2px;"><a href="users/'.$row_notificacoes['slug'].'">'.$row_notificacoes['fb_nome'].'</a></div>
                    <div style="margin-left: 5px;" class="comentario_user">'.$row_notificacoes['notificacao'].'</div>
                    <div style="margin-left: 5px;" class="tempo_do_post">'.$count.' '.$suffix.'</div> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        ';                  
}
echo json_encode($return); 
?>
```

Comment: Você sempre vai exibir todas as notificações, incluindo as que o seguidor já recebeu?

Comment: sim tipo o facebook ele tambem lista todas mesmo as que já foram lidas

Comment: Você diz a lista completa de notificações ou a notificação na barra superior? A notificação da barra somo quando você clica nela.

Comment: Veja como as notificações do Stack funcionam, elas sempre aparecem, mas perdem o status de 'novas' ou 'não lida'.

Comment: A lista completa de notificações do user actualmente logado